# Memory management in R ComplexUpset Package

Tags: r, upsetplot, complex-upset

I'm trying to plot an stacked barplot inside an upset-plot using the **ComplexUpset** package. The plot I'd like to get looks something like this (where mpaa would be component in my example):
[image]

I have a dataframe of size 57244 by 21, where one column is ID and the other is type of recording, and other 19 columns are components from 1 to 19:

```
ID  component1   component2 ... component19   type
1   1            0              1             a
2   0            0              1             b
3   1            1              0             b
```

Ones and zeros indicate affiliation with a certain component. As shown in the [example](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html) in the docs, I first convert these ones and zeros to logical, and then try to plot the basic upset plot. Here's the code:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.logical))
components <- colnames(df)[2:20]
upset(df, components, name='protein', width_ratio = 0.1)
```

But unfortunately after thinking for a while when processing the last line it spits out an error message like this:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 176.2 Mb
```

Though I know I'm using the 32Gb RAM architecture, I'm sure I couldn't have flooded the memory so much that 167 Mb can't be allocated, so my guess is I am managing memory in R somehow wrong. Could you please explein what's faulty in my code, if possible.

I also know that UpsetR package plots the same data, but as far as i know it provides no way for the stacked barplotting.

Comment: Use `sample_n`, to just get a reduced version of your data, and try it out.

Comment: @Mossa `sample_n` works for some values, and it plots the graph, but should the sampled data be used? Is there a way to use the whole dataset?

Comment: This is not a solution, but a tool for you to investigate what is going on. Maybe you have a factor with non-existing factors, or you have values that are unsubstantial, etc. If the call works with sample_n, you get to see what isn't important in the plot, and you get to tweak that.

Comment: Alright, thank you

Comment: Dig through the backtrace (the result of running `traceback()` after encountering the error) to identify the call in the stack that is trying to allocate that vector. It make also help you to read through `` ?`Memory-limits` ``.

Comment: Try increasing `min_size` or `min_degree` arguments of `upset()` to only show interesting intersections. The number of combinations in proteomics data can be huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, it works if you:

1. Tweak the `min_size` parameter so that the plot is not overloaded and makes a better impression
2. Making the first argument of `ComplexUpset` a sample with some data also helps, even if your sample is the whole dataset.